# Access denied on creating List with Graph API

Tags: list, .net, graph-api

I'm trying to create a new `List` in specific `Site` with my own `Sharepoint Application` and I'm getting `Access denied` error when I send the request to API.

My application have `Sites.ReadWrite.All`, this is the permission required to do this process following [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

I don't know what is the problem or what I'm doing wrong with this process:

```
Public Async Sub CreateList(siteId As String, name As String)
    Try
        Dim list As New List()

        Dim info As New ListInfo()
        info.Template = "genericList"

        Dim col As New ColumnDefinition()
        col.Name = "Code"
        col.Text = New TextColumn

        Dim coll As New ListColumnsCollectionPage
        coll.Add(col)

        list.DisplayName = name
        list.ListInfo = info
        list.Columns = coll

        Await GraphClient.Sites(siteId).Lists.Request.AddAsync(list)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) 'Access denied
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue.

I have tested different permissions with Application and granted admin consent to that new permissions and that runs perfectly without errors, so I think that `Microsoft Documentation` is a bit obsolete.

This procedure runs me with `Sites.FullControl.All` permission.